# custom error display with parsley.js 2.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I need to show a list of validation errors in a popup.
I've disabled UI modification with `<form data-parsley-ui-enabled="false"...` and subscribed to the "parsley:field:error" event, where I collect error information, and then on "parsley:form:validated" I display the popup, ofcourse only on the condition `isValid() == false`.
But I am having problems with getting the actual error message in the "parsley:field:error" handler. The handler gets a single parameter containing an object, which so far I inspected to have several properties:

1. $element - the actual jQuery field,
2. constraints - list of constraints
3. options.i18n - it has some raw error message strings which I can get iterating with an n variable like so: `obj.options.i18n.<LANGUAGE_CODE>.[obj.constraints[n].name]`, but they ocasionally contain placeholders (%s) and therefore are not suitable for display to the end
   user; and sometimes there's an array instead of a single string, which defeats the idea completely;

The question is, how do I get the actual error message which would got displayed if I hadn't disabled the UI?

Comment: I am aware that there is a configuration option which lets me specify the target for error messages, but that wouldn't work since the popup is created AFTER validation; that is, there's no such DOM element at the time the field is being validated. And using a persistent hidden container is a last resort measure for me.

Comment: Have a similar requirement, did you figure out how to get the message?

Comment: figured it out! added an answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

Use the following way to access a **prioritized error** message (i.e `data-parsley-priority-enabled=true`):

```
$.listen('parsley:field:error', function(parsleyField) {
    // parsley field
    console.log(parsleyField);

    // which constraint has failed
    console.log(parsleyField.validationResult[0].assert.name);

    // the data-parsley-<constraint>-message
    console.log(parsleyField.options[parsleyField.validationResult[0].assert.name+'Message']);

    // the default constraint fail message
    console.log(window.ParsleyValidator.getErrorMessage(parsleyField.validationResult[0].assert));
});
```

---

### Short Explanation

You were almost there, the messages are stored in the `options` object itself, and the format for the message is like this: `<constraint>Message`, for example: `requiredMessage`.

Which is similar to the "*data attribute to js variable conversion*" convention like in jQuery, this has been mentioned in the docs: `<parsleynamespace>-<constraint>-message` becomes `<constraint>Message`.

Got this idea after seeing the [annotated source for ui.js](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/ui.html), check the _getErrorMessage function.

---

To access all the validation messages for a field on error (i.e `data-parsley-priority-enabled=false`), you can simply iterate through the
`parsleyField.validationResult` array:

```
for (i=0; i<parsleyField.validationResult.length; i++) {
    console.log(parsleyField.options[parsleyField.validationResult[i].assert.name+'Message']);
}
```