# Display parsley errors in bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, parsley.js

I'm using parsley 2.0.0-rc5 and want display the error messages in a bootstrap tooltip. I'm using "parsley:field:error" but the event fires before the error is displayed in error-container and I can't pick up the error. Someone an idea how I get the error message for each field?

```
$.listen('parsley:field:error', function (e) {

    dataParsleyId = e.$element.attr('data-parsley-id');
    errorMsg = 'Error: ' + $('#parsley-id-'+dataParsleyId).text();

    e.$element.attr('data-original-title', errorMsg);
    e.$element.tooltip('show');

});
```

Comment: Have a similar requirement, did you figure out how to get the message?

Comment: figured it out! have added an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23138289/720508)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Guillaume Potier, the author of parsley, has added a `ParsleyUI.getErrorsMessages(parsleyFieldInstance)` method that will return an array of messages errors. It is available on master branch in [github](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/607) and would be released in next stable version.

This works perfectly for me and this is my sample code:

```
window.Parsley.on('field:error', function (fieldInstance) {
    fieldInstance.$element.popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        container: 'body',
        placement: 'right',
        content: function () {
            return fieldInstance.getErrorsMessages().join(';');
        }
    }).popover('show');
});

window.Parsley.on('field:success', function (fieldInstance) {
    fieldInstance.$element.popover('destroy');
});
```

Comment: Awesome, great help! How did you get the original errors in LI's to hide?

Comment: Just answered my own question, to turn off all UI, you just set `"data-parsley-ui-enabled"` to `false`, or `data-parsley-errors-messages-disabled` for just leaving out the error messages

Comment: As addition, you can always use `<form data-parsley-errors-messages-disabled="true">` if you don't want to show standard error containers, but still want to get popup displayed.

Comment: Works perfectly on bootstrap 3