# Parsley: classHandler not executed?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, parsley.js

I'm trying to make Parsley and Bootstrap play together according to Victor's [ideas](http://victor.stodell.se/2013/12/using-bootstrap-tooltip-to-show-parsley.html). But Parsley displays its err-msg below the input, not in the Tooltips, as Victor's code was trying to achive. So I modified the "classHandler"-fn and add console.output to see whether it is executed at all - and I'm not getting any output.

The **HTML**:

```
<form id="regform" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="name_k">Schüler <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></label>
<div class="col-lg-9"><input id="name_k" name="name_k" placeholder="Vor- und Nachname des Kindes (z.B: &quot;Karl Musterkind&quot;)" type="text" class="form-control col-lg-9" data-parsley-required="true" data-error-message="Bitte geben Sie Vor- und Nachname des Kindes an!" >
</div>
</div>
    <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Absenden">
    </form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var parsleyOptions = {
  // Sets success and error class to Bootstrap class names
  successClass: 'has-success',
  errorClass: 'has-error',

  // Bootstrap needs success/error class to be set on parent element
  errors: {
    classHandler: function(el) {
        console.log("Error-handler!");
        // return el.$element.closest(".form-group");
      return el.parent();
    },
    // Set these to empty to make sure the default Parsley elements are not rendered
    errorsWrapper: '',
    errorElem: ''
  },
  listeners: {
    // Show a tooltip when a validation error occurs
    onFieldError: function (elem, constraints, parsleyField) {
      elem.tooltip({
        animation: false,
        container: 'body',
        placement: 'top',
        title: elem.data('error-message')
      });
    },
    // Hide validation tooltip if field is validated
    onFieldSuccess: function(elem, constraints, parsleyField) {
      elem.tooltip('destroy');
    }
  }
};
          $('#regform').parsley(parsleyOptions);
});
```

I've also put together a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1x3ss6z7/3/), but unfortunately that has a CSRF-Problem when posting, so I'm not sure if that is any help at all.

As Victor's article is 2yrs old already, perhaps it refers to an Parsley 1.x? Unfortunately I'm not "getting" the doc well enough to validate this idea, there are still classHandlers being mentioned etc., and I do not have sufficient Parsley-experience to "see" that...

Comment: These options appear to be Parsley v1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008008/display-parsley-errors-in-bootstrap-tooltip), I found this code (which I modified for Parsley 2.1):

```
$.listen('field:error', function (fieldInstance) {

    arrErrorMsg = ParsleyUI.getErrorsMessages(fieldInstance);
    errorMsg = arrErrorMsg.join(';');

    fieldInstance.$element
        .popover('destroy')
        .popover({
            container: 'body',
            placement: 'right',
            content: errorMsg
        })
        .popover('show');

});

$.listen('field:success', function (fieldInstance) {
    fieldInstance.$element.popover('destroy');
});
```

But this gives me a warning about the pubsub-stuff being deprecated - I'll open a new q for that one.