# Parsley.js - Accessing UI is deprecated. Call 'getErrorsMessages' on the instance directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

After I updated Parsley.js to latest `2.7.2`, it displays this message on the console

> Accessing UI is deprecated. Call 'getErrorsMessages' on the instance directly

This is my code & working version:

```
$(".test-form").parsley({
    errorsContainer: function (ParsleyField) {
    return ParsleyField.$element.attr("title");
},
    errorsWrapper: false
});
window.Parsley.on('field:error', function (fieldInstance) {
    var messages = ParsleyUI.getErrorsMessages(fieldInstance);
  var errorMsg = messages.join(';');
  fieldInstance.$element.tooltip('dispose');
  fieldInstance.$element.tooltip({
      animation: true,
      container: 'body',
      placement: 'top',
      title: errorMsg
  });
});
window.Parsley.on('field:success', function (fieldInstance) {
    fieldInstance.$element.tooltip('dispose');
});
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/weilinzung/pen/MvZPKb

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
var messages = ParsleyUI.getErrorsMessages(fieldInstance);
```

to this:

```
var messages = fieldInstance.getErrorsMessages();
```

Answer (score 0):

Find a reference to fix it:

```
$(".test-form").parsley({
    errorsContainer: function (ParsleyField) {
    return ParsleyField.$element.attr("title");
},
    errorsWrapper: false
});

window.Parsley.on('field:error', function (fieldInstance) {
  // var messages = ParsleyUI.getErrorsMessages(fieldInstance);
  // var errorMsg = messages.join(';');
  fieldInstance.$element.tooltip('dispose');
  fieldInstance.$element.tooltip({
    animation: true,
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'top',
    title: function () {
      return fieldInstance.getErrorsMessages().join(';');
    }
  });
});

window.Parsley.on('field:success', function (fieldInstance) {
    fieldInstance.$element.tooltip('dispose');
});
```

Reference: [Display parsley errors in bootstrap tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008008/display-parsley-errors-in-bootstrap-tooltip)

Answer (score 0):

To debug Parsley to see what fields has error, I use this event handler:

```
window.Parsley.on('field:error', function (fieldInstance) {
                           console.log(fieldInstance);
                           console.log(fieldInstance.getErrorsMessages());
                  });
```